# rails models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, models, undefined

i have a model named test.rb and when i use @tests=Test.new in my controller i get the following error. Can someone temme how can i resolve this?
"undefined method `new' for Test:Module"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like test is already the name of a module called Test if would seem that you have naming conflict. Try placing your own model in a module ie

```
module MyModule
  class Test < ActiveRecord::Base  
  end
end
```

and then calling it like so

```
@test = MyModule::Test.new
```