# undefined method `new' for Test:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I have a problem of conflict of the namespace. I have a model: Test and controller TestsController. server displays an error

```
undefined method `new' for Test:Module
```

I read this question [rails models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974060/rails-models)

added to the model Test in module UserTest

```
module UserTest
  class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  end
end
```

and added to the controller

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @test = UserTest::Test.new
    @test.questions.build
    @title = "New test"
  end
 ...
end
```

server shows an error: `uninitialized constant TestsController::UserTest`

after reading more I realized that probably need to add require or include a controller. Only I do not understand how to do it. please tell me.

Comment: Your module seems unknown, do you load it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The convention in Rails is to convert your Class name in file and your module name in directory. So if you put your UserTest::Test class in test.rb file in your app/model directory, the autoload failed to get your class. Because search on `app/model/user_test/test.rb` file.

So you can "force" the require in your Controller by adding a require in top of your file. The require if you put your class in your test.rb is : `require 'test.rb'`

To know how define your require is to think the LOAD_PATH of your application add `app/model` directory. So all inside can be add directly by requiring the directory name and file name.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. question about LOAD_PATH. i added config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/) . server shows undefined method `user_test_tests_path'. what is my mistake?

Comment: method `user_test_tests_path` are generate by your route. It's not related on require system

Answer (score 12):

Never rename a model to the same name of the project. You will get a message like this:

```
undefined method `new' for Example:Module
```

The project module priority precedes on the call.