# undefined method `new' for Product:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<h2>New Product</h2>

<%= form_for @product do|f| %>
    <%= f.label :product_title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :product_title %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :key_features %><br>
    <%= f.text_area key_features %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :price %>
    <%= f.number_field :price %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :colour %>
    <%= f.number_field :colour %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :main_material %>
    <%= f.number_field :main_material %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>


class ProductsController < ApplicationController
    def home
    @product = Product.all
    end
    def new
    @product = Product.new
    end
end

class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :products do |t|
            t.string :product_title
            t.text   :key_features
            t.integer :price
            t.string :colour
            t.string :main_material

            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end
end
```

Why i'm facing that error?

Comment: You have a module `Product` somewhere and it shadows your activerecord model. Rename one of them.

Comment: The `Product` model generated using `rails g model` command or you have manually created it?

Comment: @anees manually created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you are getting this error because your app name will also be `Product`. By default your app name will be a reserved keyword and you cannot use it for naming. If this is the case, you should rename the app to something like `product_app` to use model name as `Product`. To rename the app you can refer [Renaming a Rails 4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146714/renaming-a-rails-4-app) or [How to rename a rails 5 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42326432/how-to-rename-a-rails-5-application). Hope this help.

Comment: Yeah, Done with that, Thank you for Help @AneesMuhammad'

Comment: You are welcome @Wasi. It would be nice if you could accept the answer..!

Comment: already accepted,but it takes 15 reputation to be publicly shown..!

Answer (score 0):

You need to force to require model `product.rb` because not auto loading this file on controller like

```
require 'product.rb'
```

Very good explanation on [@shingara](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9631093/4172515) answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have the model class :

file app/model/product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationModel
end
```